# How can I display multiple stations on the map using OSMFlutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation, openstreetmap

I have a list of Geo Points and I want to display the list of GeoPoints as several stations on the map using OSMFlutter.
How can I do this?

I made a list of Geo Points, but I cannot display this list as several separate stations on the map.

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:aqua_intelligent/controller/all_sites_controller.dart';
import 'package:aqua_intelligent/gen/assets.gen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_osm_plugin/flutter_osm_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class MapScreenSite extends StatefulWidget {
  MapScreenSite({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapScreenSite> createState() => _MapScreenSiteState();
}

class _MapScreenSiteState extends State<MapScreenSite> {
  MapController mapController = MapController(
      initPosition:
          GeoPoint(latitude: 49.26385496995204, longitude: -124.8238787783766),
      initMapWithUserPosition: false);

  AllSitesController allSitesController = Get.put(AllSitesController());

  @override
  void initState() {
    mapController.init();
    super.initState();
  }

  List<GeoPoint> geoPoints = [
    GeoPoint(latitude: -123.6238787783766, longitude: 48.26385496995204),
    GeoPoint(latitude: -124.8238787783766, longitude: 49.26385496995204),
    GeoPoint(latitude: -124.9238787783766, longitude: 49.36385496995204),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: OSMFlutter(
          controller: mapController,
          markerOption: MarkerOption(
            defaultMarker: MarkerIcon(
              iconWidget: Assets.img.icons.siteNormal.svg(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          showZoomController: true,
          initZoom: 6,
          maxZoomLevel: 18,
          minZoomLevel: 2,
          stepZoom: 1,
          mapIsLoading: const SpinKitCubeGrid(
            color: Colors.blue,
            size: 50.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[I want to display the stations on the map in the form of this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ6z0.png)